# Could not access envelope: Unable to create envelope from given source

Tags: web-services, soap, iis-7, spring-ws

My application produces a SOAP web service. When consumer consumes the web service sometimes user gets "Could not access envelope: Unable to create envelope from given source" error. If the same request is sent again, it processes sucessfully.

From many of the references, I found problem can be resolved by upgrading Xerces and Xalan version. I have updated both these jars still the problem persists.

Also one strange behaviour, there is no error when web service consumed with local host and port while problem comes when request is sent to https domain.

Any extra configuation to be made for handling reverse proxy or https protocol?